# Error while installing slack on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, overwrite, slack, broken-pipe

I am getting an error while installing slack. How can I solve the issue?

```
(Reading database ... 327354 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack slack-desktop-2.3.4-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking slack-desktop (2.3.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive slack-desktop-2.3.4-amd64.deb (--install):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/slack/copyright', which is also in package slack 0.15.2-5
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
slack-desktop-2.3.4-amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a previous slack version already installed. Try removing it

```
sudo apt-get remove slack
```

then repeat the installation.